# Trying to Analyze Dump File with WinDbg: PEB is Paged Out, Won't load symbols

Tags: windows, debugging, crash, windbg

Hi I'm trying to use WinDbg to look at a memory.dmp kernel dump file with the aim of diagnosing a crash. When I open the crash file and get the symbols I get the message

```
BugCheck A, {2, ff, 4e, fffff801a42ebff2}

CompressedPageDataReader warning: failed to get _SM_PAGE_KEY symbol.
CompressedPageDataReader warning: failed to get _SM_PAGE_KEY symbol.
Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShipWithIrql+12 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> .reload
Loading Kernel Symbols
..................................CompressedPageDataReader warning: failed      to get _SM_PAGE_KEY symbol.

Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000000e1`114f4018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
```

Which I assume means it can't load some of the symbols. When I try the !vad process to fix the PEB page error I get

```
0: kd> !vad 000000e1114f4018 1

VAD @ ffffca0f084164e0
Start VPN              e111400  End VPN          e1115ff  Control Area  0000000000000000
FirstProtoPte 0000000000000000  LastPte f943916c00000002  Commit Charge               21 (0n33)
Secured.Flink                0  Blink                  0  Banked/Extend                0
File Offset              50005  
  ViewUnmap NoChange PrivateMemory READWRITE
```

which doesn't correspond to what the internet tells me the result should be.

when I try the !process method I get

```
0: kd> !process 000000e1114f4018 1
Searching for Process with Cid == e1114f4018
Invalid Handle: 0x114f4018
***Could not retrieve process handle from the Cid table.  Searching...
```

which also is an error which doesn't load the symbols either. What is wrong? In either the symbol loading or the crash itself if there is enough info.

NOTE: I've tried the solutions from the MSDN page and they dont work as noted. Part of the problem is I don't know if I'm using the 000000e1`114f4018 address I'm given in the PEB paged out error message correctly in the command.

NOTE 2: Here is a link to the crash report from WinDBG. If someone can figure out the cause and explain how they figured it out that would be dandy.

https://www.scribd.com/document/326672131/Crash-Archive

Comment: Hi, I've tried the !vad and the !process method they suggest as shown above and it doesn't work .

Comment: what is **!analyze -v** showing? Can it find the symbols and show a good output?

Answer (score 2):

The PEB being paged out is normal. In order for the PEB to be present, the dump must be a full memory dump and the corresponding pages must be resident at the time of the crash.

This mostly doesn't matter because the PEB contains user mode state (user loaded modules, command line, environment variables, etc.) which generally isn't interesting for a kernel mode crash.

What IS interesting is the !analyze -v output, including the kernel mode stack of the faulting thread. Based on what you have provided, we can at least see the crash code:

BugCheck A, {2, ff, 4e, fffff801a42ebff2}

Bugcheck A is an IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, which means you have an invalid pointer dereference at an elevated IRQL (>= DISPATCH_LEVEL). The first argument is the bad address ("2") and the second argument is the IRQL ("0xFF" - this is WinDbg speak for "interrupts disabled on the processor").

In summary this means that someone has dereferenced address "2", which clearly isn't a good thing. It happened to happen with interrupts disabled on the processor, so you get an IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. The trick then is to look at the call stack and faulting instruction and figure out where the "2" came from.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through the error information it did give me and nothing jumps out as far as I can tell. If you can get a better sense of it I've posted the file in the edited question.

Comment: Well even though ON memtest scans turned up nothing replacing the memory appeared to fix the problem.